# Works by itself, but not in a loop

Tags: loops

I am using pyteaser to get information from a listing of websites.  Since there could be hundreds of sites, I am trying to put it in a loop.  When I run this code by itself:

```
summaries = SummarizeUrl(df['url'].values[1])
print (summaries)
```

It gives the following output, working fine:

[u'Bookings Institute researcher Paul C. Light published a study about failed government projects and their causes.', u'In 2011, U.K. government officials scraped a massive 9-year, $16 billion project to create a unified electronic health records system for British citizens.', u'Changing requirements, insufficient testing, and the monolithic nature of the project contributed to this failed government project for the failure.', u'Projected to cost $68 million, the projects costs skyrocketed to $700 million before being abandoned.', u'Here are a few examples of failed government projects, with estimated costs and causes:\n\nThe FBI system was designed to modernize tech systems and enable easier access across diverse FBI information assets.']

When I put it in a loop as follows:

```
i=0
for i in list(df): 
    summaries = SummarizeUrl(df['url'].values[i])
    str1 = ''.join(summaries)#convert to string
    print (str1)
```

I get the following error:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I am trying to increment i based on the value in the dataframe.  The dataframe looks like this:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khWGh.jpg)

It works when I do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You're not incrementing `i` with this. In your code `i` is not an integer. It is an object consisting of one entry of what ever `df` is.

You could try to print your `i` like:

```
for i in list(df):
   print(type(i))
   print(i)
```

to see what it is. Then you should correct you access of the url, which could be `i['url']`